# Failed to open device

Tags: linux, kernel-module, device-node

I am trying to write on the /dev/simulator file.
I have created this device by using:

> - #  mknod /dev/simulator c 60 0
> - #  chmod 666 /dev/simulator
> - #  ls -l /dev/simulator
> - crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 60, 0 2012-05-22 19:22 /dev/simulator

I am trying to open this device and write something on it, but getting an error:

> application: Simulator opening failed

which is defined by me in condition, but why am I not able to get into the device?
Here is my code:

```
/*
* Some Other Code *
*/

static int simDev;
simDev = open("/dev/simulator", O_RDWR);
if(simDev<0) {
 printf("application: Simulator opening failed.\n");
 exit (1);
}
else 
 printf("Device opened successfully.");

signal(SIGIO, signal_handler);
pid_t pid;
pid = getpid();
write(simDev, &pid, 4);

/*
* Some Other Code *
*/

close(simDev);
```

Can anyone please help me correct my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a kernel module that defines the other end of that device.

Comment: kernel Module is also written and its compiling fine.

Comment: struct file_operations sim_fops = {
 write : sim_write,
 release : sim_release,
 open : sim_open,
};

int sim_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) 
{
 /*sucess*/
 return 0;
}

int sim_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
 /*sucess*/
 return 0;
}


ssize_t sim_write(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
  int *id;
  pid = copy_from_user (&id, buf, sizeof(id));
  if(pid < 0)
    printk("Unsucess in accessing user pid %d", pid);
  else
    printk("copied pid from user : %d", pid);
  return count;
}

Comment: If i use to check the device  via :  cat /dev/simulator ---- then it gives me output like this:    cat: /dev/simulator: No such device or address

Comment: Likely the module has not been loaded, or is non-functional.